# Call Apex REST service from VF Page and display the result in Pop up

Tags: apex, rest-service

There will be a custom image beside a text box and on the click of that I want to invoke a Apex REST service written in another sandbox and show the results returned from the web service in a popup. How to achieve the same in a `Visualforce Page`?

Comment: You have already written the flow. What is stopping you from implementation, are you stuck at any specific issue?

Comment: i need the code to implement the same.I need the click code to call the rest service and display the same in popup.I am new to it and not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, If you're new, I'd suggest you to first learn and try something before asking for a code. Community members would be happy to help if you are stuck on a specific issue. If you want whole solution/code, maybe hire a consultant or freelance developer.